# Changing Google Maps Infowindow background colour

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

Is it possible to change the white background and border styles of Google Maps API infowindow? I know I can pass custom HTML as content but the white edges are still visible. If it's not possible is using infobox the only other option?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For customized the background you have to refer to **InfoBubble** of **Google maps utility library**:
https://github.com/googlemaps/js-info-bubble

Otherwise, here is a nice tutorial for your asking:
http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2014/02/custom-google-maps-info-windows/

Hope that'll help you

Comment: Nice one, thanks! The last link should work best for this situation.

Comment: https://artandlogic.com/2014/02/custom-google-maps-info-windows/ 

they slightly changed the link.